# Знак рубля не отображается в Android приложении

Tags: android, qt, unicode

Вот он герой моего вопроса - `₽`. 
Вместо него в приложении отображается симпатичный квадратик. Это знак начал неожиданно возвращаться из Google Play Billing Library вместе с ценой (in-app billing). Покупатели в панике. Приложение написано на C++ и Qt.

Устройство - какойто там сумсанг с андроидом 4.4.2

Как его можно отобразить?

p.s. в Google Play тоже не отображается

Answer (score 6):

Не знаю, исследовали ли вы эту тему или нет, но символ рубля появился сравнительно недавно (по сравнению c $), и далеко не во всех шрифтах он есть. Поэтому, вы далеко не первый, кто сталкивается с проблемой отображения символа рубля.

1. Самое, на мой взгляд, простое `<strike>P</strike>` // <strike>P</strike>
2. Использовать картинку: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ruble_sign.svg
3. Использовать шрифт от Лебедева: http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/html/rouble/

*больше информации по этому вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665622/russian-ruble-symbol-html-code

Comment: Вот еще, очень полезный ресурс в этом плане:
http://unicode-table.com/ru/20BD/

Comment: Просто гениально про strike

Answer (score 5):

[Вот](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto#charset) шрифт, в котором после последнего январского обновления добавился символ рубля.

Comment: Не вижу ссылки для скачивания. И что, мне таскать этот шрифт с моим приложением?

Comment: @zenden2k а в чём проблема? Я всегда в ассетах шрифт нужный таскаю. Весит он копейки.

Comment: @Suvitruf, не такие уж и копейки, от 126 до 168 Кб на один шрифт. Хотя да, не так много.